# browser not opening new web page and focusing on the managed webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, internet-explorer, browser

i have an issue with the Internet Explorer object.
i have a managed website application opening via InterentExplorer object.
when trying to open the internet explorer externally, the explorer will focus on the old managed website and will not open new initialized web page.
this is how i open my managed website:

```
InterentExplorer IE = new InterentExplorer()
IE.Visible = true;
IE.Navigae(url);
```

How to reproduce the issue:

1. open internet explorer (manually not in the code)
2. run the managed website (my short code line)
3. close internet explorer (manually not in the code)
4. the focus will be on the managed website and the new webpage will not open
   the url is the managed application that apperently creating the problem but i have no posibility to change the application only to make a change in the code above.
   the issue that i realized is that when i open my managed application,its not opening another process and when i'm trying to open the browser,its indicates that iexplore was already open and doesnt open another browser(maybe problem with the handle id?)
   Is it posible to open interent explorer with navigate or navigate2 function as a new process when one iexplore process is already running?

Comment: i think this is the main thing i'm trying to acomplish: to open interent explorer with navigate or navigate2 function as a new process when one iexplore process is already running

Comment: Is it possible to open IE object in a new process when iexplore process is already open?